# Type Error Microbit Rock Paper Sciccors Project

Tags: python, micropython, bbc-microbit

I have a type error but can't seem to fix it.

```
from microbit import *
import random
import radio

radio.on()

randomnummer = 0

while True:
    if accelerometer.current_gesture("shake"):
        #geschud (feelsgoodman)
        randomnummer = random.randint(0,2)

        #output test
        display.show(str(randomnummer))
        sleep(1000)
        display.clear()

        if randomnummer == 0:
            #vuur jammie
            #display.show(Image.HAPPY) als test
            display.show(Image.HAPPY)

        elif randomnummer == 1:
            #grasjes
            #display.show(Image.ANGRY) als test
            display.show(Image.ANGRY)

        elif randomnummer == 2:
            #watra
            #display.show(Image.HEART) als test
            display.show(Image.HEART)

        else:
            #error omg
            #display.show(Image.SAD) als test
            display.show(Image.SAD)

    else:
        #niet geschud (feelsbadman)
        display.show("-")


sleep(500)
```

The `radio` isn't yet implemented, but I get the error on the line:

```
if accelerometer.current_gesture("shake"):
```

I hope some of you might see the mistake I just made here.

Answer (score 1):

accelerometer.current_gesture() is a function that returns the name of the current gesture, not compare it. you should do the comparing yourself:

```
if accelerometer.current_gesture() == "shake":
```

I personally don't know anything about microbit, but you can try it and if it works then all good.

Comment: Hey that worked out, the rest of the code now isn't working like intended but this worked ty :D